# chefのautomaticの使い方

Tags: chef

chef の node に、automatic と書くことが多いようですが、何につかっているでしょうか？

Comment: 具体的にNodeに書かれているautomaticの内容を提示出来ますか？automaticはattributesの一種なのでレシピ等から参照して使います。nodeにautomaticを書く意図は作者によって違うかもしれません。knife solo prepare を実行した場合は自動的に node ファイルに automatic が書かれる場合もあります。